# Issue with Graph API in Power automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am trying to get all users out of a tenant with power automate.
But when i try to filter out users with userType Member.
I keep getting the error:
Enter a Valid URI ( even tough i am using a valid URI that is used inside the docs)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify `$filter` query in URI but add it to `Queries`.

Example (not sure if I'm using the same trigger):

[image]